# Flask Cors not blocking requests from undesired origins

Tags: python, flask, cors, flask-cors

I'm testing out a flask REST api and I would like to restrict access to the api from all origins except for local development and a certain url once it's in production by using flask-cors. I thought setting the CORS_ORIGINS config would do the trick but it still allows requests to the api. I then tried the method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58935866/flask-cors-is-not-denying-origins-as-configured) but I still get valid requests. The api is running on `localhost:5000/api` and I am opening up an http server separately using `python3 -m http.server` which is running on `localhost:8000`. When I use `await fetch('http://localhost:5000')` from the http server's developer tools console I still get valid requests, even though these should be blocked, correct?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

cors = CORS()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(CORS_ORIGINS="http://localhost:5000")
    cors.init_app(app, resources={"r/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:5000"}})
    
    @app.route('/api')
    def api():
        return jsonify({'success': "Healthy: OK"}), 201

    return app
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Or is there a better way to restrict access to my api so it is only available locally or from a specific domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CORS is usually enforced by browsers. What it does is that it prevents your web page from making request and showing data from servers other than it originated from, except in case it is allowed in ALLOW_ORIGINS headers by the server. The problem you are facing is that you are unable to enforce CORS. I suspect that might be because you are using localhost. Because many browsers have relaxed SOPs for localhost in order to allow seamless development. You might have to deploy your server and web page on different servers in order to face CORS.
I hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's still allowing me to connect even when I run the app on a different computer outside of the network. I have it running behind a reverse proxy though, could this cause issues with cors?

Comment: check referer-policy of your browser. It should be strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working now, though I did have to deploy it to my other server, so you were right I believe it was an issue with the local development. The config doesn't seem to do anything for me, but initializing using the `resources={}` option worked.